# Reading a list of lists from a file as list of lists in python

Tags: python, file, list

I collected data in the form of list of lists and wrote the data into a text file. The data in the text file looks like

```
[[123231,2345,888754],[223467,85645]]
```

I want to read it back and store in a list of lists in my program. But when I do `read()` from the file and try creating a flat list then it takes everything as a string and the interpretation changes totally and i am not able to query the result I get after reading as normal list of lists in python.

Can someone help me with reading the file and storing in the same format as list of lists?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you make your question more clean?

Answer (score 9):

This looks like valid [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

So you can simply do:

```
import json
with open(myfilename) as f:
    lst = json.load(f)
```

To store your "list of lists" in a file, do

```
with open(myfilename, "w") as f:
    json.dump(lst, f)
```

Comment: How is this a valid JSON? There is no double quotes. There is no key value pair. Can you please explain?

Comment: @PranavNandan: Why should there be? Not all JSON objects are key/value pairs. `json.loads("[[123231,2345,888754],[223467,85645]]")` returns `[[123231,2345,888754],[223467,85645]]`.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example, specifically the part about arrays.

Comment: I tried with the suggested command, and got error "
 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)"  any recommendations?

Comment: @user17302: Did you use the input from the question or some other (if so, can you share it)?

Answer (score 2):

You could just [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) your data instead. To save it:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> p= [[123231,2345,888754],[223467,85645]]  
>>> with open("data.txt", "wb") as internal_filename:
...     pickle.dump(p, internal_filename)
```

To load it:

```
>>> with open("data.txt", "rb") as new_filename:
...     pp = pickle.load(new_filename)
>>> pp
[[123231, 2345, 888754], [223467, 85645]]
```

This is also useful for much more elaborate objects.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use `eval` to achieve this, but the other solutions maybe better:

```
# reading a list from a file
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
l = eval(f.read())

# storing a list to a file
outf = open('out','w')
outf.write(str(l))
```

Sometime using `eval` is a bad practice. For more information check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- the file that the list data is in is a python file
- the list data is assigned to a variable
- the file is in a python module

You can then import the list from the python file. 
For example say that list, my_list, is in the file
mylist.py

E.g:

```
# This is the file mylist.py
my_list = [[123231,2345,888754],[223467,85645]]
```

You can then treat my_list as a python list

```
from mylist import my_list

for item in mylist:
   print "item = <", item, ">"
```