# Reading a file with multiple list of lists from into python

Tags: python, import

This question is very similar to [Reading a list of lists from a file as list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294310/reading-a-list-of-lists-from-a-file-as-list-of-lists-in-python), except that the file I have has multiple lines with list of lists, such as

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
[[1], [4], [6], [1,2,3]]
[[]]
[[1,5]]
```

Following the advice from above link, my below attempt failed

```
import json
f = open('idem_perms.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    e = json.load(line)
```

throws the error

```
--> 287     return loads(fp.read(),
    288         encoding=encoding, cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    289         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) should be [`loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

The first function expects a file object and the second expects a string.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json

with open('idem_perms.txt', 'r') as file:
    result = [json.loads(line) for line in file.readlines()]

print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], [[1], [4], [6], [1, 2, 3]], [[]], [[1, 5]]]
```